# Example of injective ring homomorphism that is not flat.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, flatness

What is a good example of an injective ring homomorphism $f: A \rightarrow B$ that is not flat, i.e. such that $B$ is not a flat $A$-module?
Examples of non-flat modules I've seen usually involve an element $a \in A$ such that $aB = 0$, hence not injective, like $\mathbb{Z}_2$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the examples you know to construct an injective example.

For instance, take the morphism $f:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_2:n\to (n, \overline{n})$.  Then $f$ is injective, but $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is not a flat $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ is not flat because if I consider $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ as the multiplication by 2 then $n\otimes (0,\bar{1}) \in \mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ will be sent to 0, is that correct?

Comment: @user113988 That is correct.  You could also use the fact that a module is flat if and only if all its direct summands are flat.